# Spring batch - hibernate integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch

i'm working on a batch project that uses the spring batch core library
the library uses jdbcTemplate to persist jobs meta data

and i'm trying to use hibernate in order to read the data about a specific job

```
package com.ben.batch.repository;

import org.springframework.batch.core.JobInstance;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

public interface JobInstanceRepository extends JpaRepository<JobInstance,Long> {

    @Query("select count(j) from JobInstance j where j.jobName in :jobName ") //Can't resolve symbol 'JobInstance'
    Long countBuJobName(String jobName);
}
```

in ordinary spring boot project this works but now it shows this error

> Can't resolve symbol 'JobInstance'

tho I imported the class correctly

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the spring batch infrastructure is not yet available as spring-data repository, see this [JIRA Ticket BATCH-2203](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2203)

Comment: yes but i'm asking if it's possible to use hibernate for an existing db like the one used by the spring-batch-core project

Comment: sure, just create JPA "JobInstance", "JobExecution",...etc. classes and use them, spring batch does not provide them

Answer (score 1):

For similar purposes exists JobRepository
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/JobRepository.html
It allows you to fetching any information regarding your jobs.

Answer (score 0):

`JobInstance` is not a Hibernate entity ([source code for reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/2.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/core/JobInstance.java)). You'll need to implement your own Hibernate persistence layer if you'd like to query the tables using Hibernate. The primary reason for this is that the framework allows you to define any table prefix you like so your tables would end up as **BATCH_**JOB_EXECUTION, **NIGHTLY_**JOB_EXECUTION, **ABCD_**JOB_EXECTION, etc. Because of that the Hibernate model wouldn't know what table names to point to.